# Casting undefined JSON into new JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Undefined JSON is returned to a Node.js/Express.js app from a URL api endpoint `http : // someserver:someport / some_api_url?_var1=1`.  This undefined JSON input will always have the same format, and needs to be cast into a new JSON object by the receiving code (shown below).  The new JSON object can then be processed in various ways, including being passed into HTML.

---

**THE OP QUESTION:**

---

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that:**

1.) JSON in the form of  `{"1":"descriptive string"}` gets cast into a newly defined JSON object called `dataElement` with two properties, `dataElement.dataKey` and `dataElement.descriptionString`?

2.) The html response sent back to the user's web browser includes `dataElement.dataKey` and `dataElement.descriptionString` in the UI format:

```
Index is: 1  
Description is: descriptive string
```

---

**EXAMPLE CODE TO BE MODIFIED:**

---

For starters, the code that needs to be modified is:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  var url = 'http://someserver:someport/some_api_url?_var1=1'  

  http.get(url, function (resInner) {
    var body = '';

    resInner.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    resInner.on('end', function () {
      var fullResponse = JSON.parse(body); 

    // code to parse JSON into new JSON object, which is passed into HTML
    var indexStr = key;
    var descriptionStr = fullResponse[key];
    var dataElement = {"dataKey" : key, "descriptionString" : descriptionStr};
    var htmlResp = 'Index is: '+${dataElement.dataKey}+'<br> Description is: '+${dataElement.descriptionString};
    res.send(htmlResp);

  });
}).on('error', function (e) {
  console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});

});
```

---

**THE CURRENT ERROR:**

---

At the moment, the above code is giving the following error:

```
/home/user/nodejs_apps/express_helloworld/myapp/app.js:139
      var htmlResp = 'Index is: '+${dataElement.dataKey}+'<br> Description is: '+${dataElement.descriptionString};
                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:142:18)
    at node.js:939:3
```

Comment: Where is `key` coming from ?

Comment: So you have a variable `key` defined somewhere else then, and the API returns valid JSON where one of the keys is actually the same as what you've set the `key` variable to

Comment: So you don't have a `key` variable then?

Comment: *"The OP..."*, which stands for *"Original Poster"* is you? Anyway, try this -> https://jsfiddle.net/qdafy9w1/

Comment: Yeah, didn't think about *"Original Posting"*, I usually read OP as *"..the one who asked the question"* and got somewhat confused? If it takes a long time, it has to be the call and the async functions, parsing a small object and accessing the keys etc. should only take milliseconds.

Comment: I've edited my answer, and reposted it.

Comment: @adeneo I have deleted my comments, to make it easier for readers to go directly from the question to your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from your string concatenation, which seems to be using some invalid templating language, and the `key` variable, which isn't defined, you have to actually get the keys with `Object.keys` etc.

Try it this way instead

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var url = 'http://someserver:someport/some_api_url?_var1=1'

    http.get(url, function(resInner) {
        var body = '';

        resInner.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        resInner.on('end', function() {
            var fullResponse = JSON.parse(body);

            // code to parse JSON into new JSON object, which is passed into HTML
            var keys     = Object.keys(fullResponse);
            var firstKey = keys[0];
            var descriptionStr = fullResponse[firstKey];
            var dataElement = {
                "dataKey": firstKey,
                "descriptionString": descriptionStr
            };
            var htmlResp = 'Index is: ' + dataElement.dataKey + '<br> Description is: ' + dataElement.descriptionString;

            res.send(htmlResp);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you're trying to use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but you are using them incorrectly, causing an error. This is the format of template strings:

```
`Hello World, the expression "1+2" evaluates to ${1+2}` ==> `Hello World, the expression "1+2" evaluates to 3`
```

Template strings use backticks, what you use to insert inline code here at SE. So, your problem line is supposed to look like this:

```
var htmlResp = `Index is: ${dataElement.dataKey}`<br> Description is: `${dataElement.descriptionString}`;
```

Other than that syntax error, I couldn't see any problems with your code, but who knows? ;)

Hope I could be helpful!